# how to access cloudfront to s3 bucket object simple url

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, aws-sdk

i am trying to access cloudfront to s3 bucket object response "AccessDenied".
xxxxxxxxxxxxx.cloudfront.net/bucket_name/35.jpg

inside bucket i can access url this is "public" url.
https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/bucket_name/35.jpg

I am also try another bucket with another cloudfront ID with signed URL result is same. Please view code here =>
[amazon cloudfront Error "AccessDenied"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40512022/amazon-cloudfront-error-accessdenied?noredirect=1#comment68276499_40512022)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should:

- Configure your CloudFront distribution with an **Origin** to point to your S3 bucket
- Access the content via: `xxxx.cloudfront.net/35.jpg`

See:

- [Using Amazon S3 Origins and Custom Origins for Web Distributions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/DownloadDistS3AndCustomOrigins.html)
- [Using CloudFront with Amazon S3](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/MigrateS3ToCloudFront.html)
- [Task List for Creating a Web Distribution](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/distribution-web-creating.html)